# update jqPlot with json data (flicker)

Tags: json, jqplot

So I've put this together from a bunch of examples around the internet.  I'm pulling data from a text file and plotting it with jqPlot.  I'm then recalling a function to continually update the plot from the file:

```
<div id="chart1" style="height:300px; width:500px;"></div>
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">


  // Our ajax data renderer which here retrieves a text file.
  // it could contact any source and pull data, however.
  // The options argument isn't used in this renderer.
  var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
        var ret = null;
    $.ajax({
            // have to use synchronous here, else the function 
        // will return before the data is fetched
        async: false,
        url: url,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
             ret = data;
        }
        });
    return ret;
  };

  // The url for our json data
  var jsonurl = "./jsondata.txt";

  // passing in the url string as the jqPlot data argument is a handy
  // shortcut for our renderer.  You could also have used the
  // "dataRendererOptions" option to pass in the url.
  var plot1;



$(document).ready(function(){

  plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', jsonurl,{
    title: "MY GRAPH",
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    dataRendererOptions: {
        unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
        }
  });

    ConstantPlotter();
});


function ConstantPlotter() {

  plot1.destroy();
  plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', jsonurl,{
    title: "MY GRAPH",
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    dataRendererOptions: {
        unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
        }
  });

  setTimeout(ConstantPlotter,100)
}

</script>
```

It works fine, but the plot flickers badly since it's being destroyed and recreated every time.  The problem is that when I try to replace the 'destroy and plot' code with

```
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', jsonurl,{
    title: "MY GRAPH",
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    dataRendererOptions: {
        unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
        }
  }).replot();
```

it works beautifully but I get a terrible memory leak.

Does anyone know a way to constantly update this plot from the file without having the terrible flicker?  Thanks!